# TypeScript compiled module declares var before auto invoking function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am porting an existing AngularJS (1.x) project to TypeScript, so far code is working, but I'm wondering why this is happening.

In JavaScript I am declaring a module like so:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myModule', []);
})();
```

In Typescript like so:

```
module myModule {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myModule', []);
}
```

Which is compiled to this:

```
var myModule;
(function (myModule) {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("myModule", []);
})(myModule || (myModule = {}));
```

I have few doubts:

1. Isn't it wrong to add to the global scope `var myModule`?
2. Why is `myModule` being passed to the anonymous function?
3. Since the `var myModule` is added, I wonder if I should avoid overwriting. I separate module declaration from, say, the Controller. I wonder, when I declare the controller, should I use a different `module` name?

In other words, can I reuse the same name for the second module, like so

```
module myModule {
    angular
      .module('myModule')
      .controller('myController');
}
// which will "overwrite" the preexisting var myModule
```

Or would it be better to use another name for the module, like so:

```
module myModuleController {
    angular
      .module('myModule')
      .controller('myController');
}
// which will generate another var myModule
```

I have already seen that the code works equally fine, but I'm sure that there are certain things I should know on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doing that so you'll be able to access this module from other places, for example:

```
module ModuleA {
    export var num = 4;
}

module ModuleB {
    export function log() {
        console.log(ModuleA.num);
    } 
}
```

You can also then add more to the same module:

```
module ModuleA {
    export var num = 4;
}

module ModuleA {
    export var str = "string";
}

console.log(ModuleA.num); // 4
console.log(ModuleA.str); // string
```

In the compiled js in your example `myModule` is being passed so that the new definitions will be added to the existing module if there is one, or `{}` if not.
The compiled js in my (2nd) example is:

```
var ModuleA;
(function (ModuleA) {
    ModuleA.num = 4;
})(ModuleA || (ModuleA = {}));
var ModuleA;
(function (ModuleA) {
    ModuleA.str = "string";
})(ModuleA || (ModuleA = {}));
```

As you can see in the 2nd time `ModuleA` won't be empty and so adding the `str` variable will be done on the previous defined module.

Note that this behavior is only true when you're not using a module system, for example this:

```
export module ModuleA {
    export var num = 4;
}
```

Compiles into:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    var ModuleA;
    (function (ModuleA) {
        ModuleA.num = 4;
    })(ModuleA = exports.ModuleA || (exports.ModuleA = {}));
});
```

(with the default module system)

Comment: Thanks, much clearer :-). One question though, since I'm in AngularJS, should I use define?

Comment: I'm not an angular developer so I can't answer from experience, but as a whole the javascript world is moving to module loaders. Check this article I found: [AngularJS 1.x with TypeScript (or ES6) Best Practices](https://codepen.io/martinmcwhorter/post/angularjs-1-x-with-typescript-or-es6-best-practices). It recommends using that approach